# Web2py application: How to reference .yaml file in controller?

Tags: python-2.7, yaml, web2py

I have an app running online under `web2py`. Now, i am adding `names.yml` file which i need to call in my controller file `(default.py)` on web2py server. where should I keep the `.yml/.yaml` files. Currently I have kept them in views with `default/names.yml` but when I call it in default.py like:

```
dicttagger = DictionaryTagger([ 'default/names.yml', 'default/surname.yml'])
```

i get no such file error.
Also tried below:

```
dicttagger = DictionaryTagger([ 'views/default/names.yml', 'views/default/surname.yml'])
```

same error

class snapshot as under:

```
class DictionaryTagger(object):

    def __init__(self, dictionary_paths):
        files = [open(path, 'r') for path in dictionary_paths]
        dictionaries = [yaml.load(dict_file) for dict_file in files]
        map(lambda x: x.close(), files)
```

Any suggestions as how to do this or am I making mistake of using yaml/yml file in we2py and it doesn't work in web2py app hosted online?

question 2

thank you. it resolved an error but I am not sure how to add nltk.download() into my hosted app. I keep getting the below error. Can you pls have a look:
Traceback
1.
2.
3.
4.
5.
6.
7.
8.
9.
10.
11.
12.
13.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/prakashsukhwal/web2py/gluon/restricted.py", line 220, in restricted
    exec ccode in environment
  File "/home/prakashsukhwal/web2py/applications/Sensiva/controllers/default.py", line 4, in 
    nltk.download()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 644, in download
    self._interactive_download()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 958, in _interactive_download
    DownloaderShell(self).run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 981, in run
    user_input = raw_input('Downloader> ').strip()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
Error snapshot  help
(EOF when reading a line)

inspect attributes

Frames

File /home/prakashsukhwal/web2py/gluon/restricted.py in restricted at line 220 code arguments variables

File /home/prakashsukhwal/web2py/applications/Sensiva/controllers/default.py in  at line 4 code arguments variables

File /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/downloader.py in download at line 644 code arguments variables

File /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/downloader.py in _interactive_download at line 958 code arguments variables

File /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/downloader.py in run at line 981 code arguments variables

Function argument list

(self=)

Code listing

```
def run(self):
    print 'NLTK Downloader'
    while True:
        self._simple_interactive_menu(
            'd) Download', 'l) List', ' u) Update', 'c) Config', 'h) Help', 'q) Quit')
        user_input = raw_input('Downloader> ').strip()

        if not user_input: print; continue
        command = user_input.lower().split()[0]
        args = user_input.split()[1:]
        try:
```

Variables

user_input  undefined
builtinraw_input    
).strip undefined
Context

Comment: It would probably be better to post question 2 as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the files wherever you want, but if you're using the Python `open` function, you'll need to give it full paths, not paths relative to the web2py application folder. Instead, try:

```
import os

dicttagger = DictionaryTagger([os.path.join(request.folder, 'views',
                                            'default', 'names.yml'),
                               ...])
```

Comment: thank you for helping me. :) 
could you please help with the question 2 as well